# Library missing for jsp:include

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I am declaring the jsp namespace in my xhtml faces pages using xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/jsp/page"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
      xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/jsp/page"
      xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

However the jsp:include directive is not being processed, just rendered. My IDE (Netbeans) tells me that it cannot find the library for this namespace. I am using maven with the following pom.xml file. I have another application deployed into the same container, which uses a similar structure, but is not using maven. I can't for the live of me figure out what library I need to include to get any of the jsp:directives working.

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.j2anywhere.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>JSFDebug</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>JSFDebug</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>            
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>            
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
</properties>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Facelets, which is basically the successor of JSP. It are two entirely distinct view technologies. The one is XML based and the other is Servlet based. You can't use JSP tags in Facelets, nor can you use Facelets tags in JSP.

You need to use Facelets' own [`<ui:include>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/include.html) instead.

```html
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/foo.xhtml" />
```

Forget about JSP at all when developing with Facelets.

#### See also:

- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Introduction to Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html)
- [Facelets tag library documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/)

Comment: I would agree with you, but I have another application working using just about the same libraries and page setup. That is what is confusing me.

Comment: Apparently it was a JSP page instead of a Facelets page, or it was *actually* `<ui:include>`.

Comment: Apparently I was wrong. It wasn't working in the other application either. Strange that some things make perfect sense at 03:00 am and then again no sense at all when you wake up. Thanks for your help.